# Can't control brightness on HP Pav dv6t running Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, power-management

I installed FC 16 on my HP Pavilion dv6 with a 9-cell battery. I get approximately 7-8 hours on Windows 7, but at best 3 hours on Fedora. I cannot adjust the screen brightness using the fn keys, nor can I adjust it through software.

`lspci | grep VGA` gives me:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Seymour [AMD Radeon HD 6470M]

My kernel version is 3.1.5-1.fc16.x86_64

Comment: for Ubuntu,
https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight
 fixes that. Perhaps this info will help.(I haven't used Fedora much lately)